# How to push dataframe(which contain excel sheet) to mysql in python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, amazon-s3, mysql-python

I am reading data from S3 by python and trying to write into mysql database but while doing this i am facing an error.

Any help highly appreciated!

```
from pandas.io import sql
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + ':' + str(port) + '/' + database , echo=False)

df.to_sql(con=engine, name='pna_data', if_exists='replace')
```

Error:

`InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1059, "Identifier name 'Quantity at Regenersis India PVT LTD. Central warehouse - Bangalore' is too long") [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE pna_data (\n\tindex BIGINT, \n\tService Order Code TEXT, \n\tVendor TEXT, \n\tTableauPSL TEXT, \n\tService Station TEXT, \n\tCustomer Name TEXT, \n\tCustomer Contact Number BIGINT, \n\tCustomer Mobile Number FLOAT(53), \n\tCustomer Email TEXT, \n\tOld IMEI 1 FLOAT(53), \n\tOld IMEI 2 FLOAT(53), \n\tIMEI 1 TEXT, \n\tIMEI 2 FLOAT(53), \n\tProduct Model TEXT, \n\tPurchase Date DATETIME, \n\tService Type TEXT, \n\tIsWarrantyApplicable TEXT, \n\tIs CID TEXT, \n\tCreate Time DATETIME, \n\tApply for Parts Time DATETIME, \n\tDOA TEXT, \n\tProblem Category TEXT, \n\tDefective Part PN FLOAT(53), \n\tDefective Part Name TEXT, \n\tReplacement Part PN FLOAT(53), \n\tReplacement Part Name TEXT, \n\tInventory Qty at Service center FLOAT(53), \n\tQuantity at B2X Mumbai Central warehouse FLOAT(53), \n\tQuantity at OnePlus - Bangalore Main Warehouse FLOAT(53), \n\tQuantity at Regenersis India PVT LTD. Central warehouse - Bangalore FLOAT(53), \n\tIntransit Quantity FLOAT(53), \n\tShipment Date DATETIME, \n\tShipping Status TEXT, \n\tLogistic name TEXT, \n\tAWB No. TEXT, \n\tTAT FLOAT(53), \n\tRequest Status TEXT, \n\tPart status TEXT, \n\tPNA TEXT, \n\tCreatedDate TEXT, \n\tUpdatedDate TEXT, \n\tPNA_Resolved_Date TEXT\n)\n\n']`

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)

Comment: Identifers in MySQL can only be 64 characters long. 'Quantity at Regenersis India PVT LTD. Central warehouse - Bangalore' is longer than that.

Comment: what to do now? how to remove this error and write data into database. I have created a table pna_data with same columns. can you please elaborate how to get it done.

Comment: its not i have changed column name still not working same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is literally taking some row of data and trying to create a table from it.

```
CREATE TABLE pna_data ( ...
    Quantity at Regenersis India PVT LTD. Central warehouse - Bangalore FLOAT(53)
    ...
)
```

Thus, you get the error

> Identifier name ... is too long

I suggest you rename the columns in the input data to something less verbose and also denormalize the data, e.g.

```
quantity   | location                                       | country
-----------|------------------------------------------------|---------
100        | "Regenersis India PVT LTD. Central warehouse"  | "Bangalore"
```

If you want to, you can rename/modify/separate columns in Pandas before you even attempt to do `df.sql`